# How to trace all files opened by a process and its child processes?

Tags: windows, process

I tried Sysinternals  - Process Monitor, but there is no way to dynamically attach filters for child processes

Comment: I know it's only one level but ProcMon allows you to filter based on the Parent PID. Is this what you need?

Comment: this works only for one level. I need details for grand-child and so on

Answer (score 4):

To make it programming related: you can use [Import Address Table Hooking](http://jpassing.com/2008/01/06/using-import-address-table-hooking-for-testing/) and dole out your own implementation :-)

If you are looking for a tool, I believe someone has already done that for you: [StraceNT: A system call tracer for Windows](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=Strace.htm).

The website claims it is an strace clone and strace supports tracing child processes (I haven't used this tool myself, so not sure of the claim).

(strace is a utility available on linux environments, which allows you to trace system calls, I suppose that explains the name straceNT).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hm, couldn't get it to work. Every time it just spat “Error: The request is not supported.”

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenedFilesView from Nirsoft. 
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

The download is on the bottom of the page. (Actually hard to find)

Answer (score -1):

Try Process Monitor. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx by Microsoft.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. **Mark Russinovich** is giving us the best internals for windows since Windows NT.